# [Dynamic 365]How can i know the key and the joining table Inside advance find function?

Tags: dynamics-365

My D365 CRM instance is customized by other people.
For the "lookup type" column, how can I know which key and which table to lookup?

Is it black box?

[image: screeshot]

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the entity metadata, which you can access by going to Settings > Customizations > Customize the system.

Select the entity on the list, then "N:1 Relationships" (or "1:N Relationships") and you will see the information about the field.[image: relationships]

Alternatively, you can also go to Fields, then double click on the field name and you will see this info on a new window.

[image: Fields]

[image: info about the lookup]

About the key used by the lookup, it's the primary key of the referenced entity (so here `systemuserid`)

---

On a side note, I highly recommend using [XRM toolbox](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/) for doing that (and a lot more things) faster, the plugin in this case is "Metadata Browser".

Comment: thank a lot!i only have option "Developer resources" inside customization.So i guess i would be disabled by our vendor.

Comment: Yes, that mean you're lacking the necessary permission. If it's a standard entity, you can find the information on the documentation ([here account for example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/entities/account)), otherwise yes, you have to guess :D

Comment: Oh Thanks.btw where to set the permission?

Comment: That's a  bigger topic, but [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/security-roles-privileges) you can find info about it.

Answer (score 0):

In **"Developer resources"** locate the web api url, it should look like this:

`https://.../.../api/data/v9.0/`

Copy this url, append the following, change the logical name, and paste it in the browser

`https://.../.../api/data/v9.0/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='put the name of the entity name that has the lookup column here')?$select=LogicalName&$expand=Attributes($filter=AttributeType eq Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AttributeTypeCode'Lookup')`

Copy the result and format/beautify it using something like [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html), you shall easily find the lookup field information and it's referenced entity in the "Targets".

This information doesn't require any special permissions.